# C# counter game console application

Tags: c#, console

```
var choices = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "Rock" }, { 2, "Paper" }, { 3, "Scissors" } };
int input;
var randomly = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "Rock" }, { 2, "Paper" }, { 3, "Scissors" } };

Random random = new Random();
int RandomNumber = random.Next(1, 4);

do
{
    //Counter
    double Wins = 0.0;
    int Losses = 0;
    int Ties = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("-- Weapons Menu --");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("1] Rock");
    Console.WriteLine("2] Paper");
    Console.WriteLine("3] Scissors");
    Console.WriteLine("Choose Your Weapon [1, 2 or 3]:");
    Console.WriteLine();
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (input == RandomNumber)
        Console.WriteLine("You Tied The Computer");
    Ties++;
    //Winning 
    ++Wins;
    if (input == 1 && RandomNumber == 3)

    Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");


    if (input == 2 && RandomNumber == 1)

    Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");


    if (input == 3 && RandomNumber == 2)

    Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");

    //Lossing 
    ++Losses;
    if (input == 1 && RandomNumber == 2)
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry You Lost To The Computer :(");

    if (input == 2 && RandomNumber == 3)
        Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");

    if (input == 3 && RandomNumber == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Player Chose {0} : Computer Chose {1}", choices[input], randomly[RandomNumber]));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("<Press Any Key To Continue...>");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Player Wins      Computer Wins");
    Console.WriteLine("----------       --------------");
    Console.WriteLine(" {0}                {1}", Wins, Losses);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
while (input != 4) ;
Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
```

The code runs fine although i am unable to get the record of wins and losses correctly after each game is complete.

Comment: Try not to post too much code.  Consider editing it to show just the relevant sections.  See _[mcve]_. Check-out the _[faq]_  and _[ask]_.

Comment: `Ties`, `Wins`, and `Losses` are all incremented every time. I think you do not understand how to use curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

this code is your issue (as well as further down with wins/Losses)

```
        if (input == RandomNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("You Tied The Computer");
        Ties++;
```

it needs to be written as:

```
        if (input == RandomNumber){
            Console.WriteLine("You Tied The Computer");
            Ties++;
        }
```

explaination:  Currently you are outputting Tied only if the `input == randomnumber` which is fine,  but you are increasing Ties by 1 regardless of if it's a tie or not.   same with winning and same with losses.

An IF statement will only execute the next line. If you have more then 1 line you need executed as a result of the If statement,  then you need to wrap those multiple lines in { }

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikerym's answer: for the winning and losing logic, combine the three "if" statements into a single "if" statement, and move the increment statement into the "then" block.

```
if ((input == 1 && RandomNumber == 3) || 
    (input == 2 && RandomNumber == 1) ||
    (input == 3 && RandomNumber == 2)) {

    Console.WriteLine("You Beat The Computer :)");
    Wins++;
}
```

Same idea for losses.  The way your program is written, you are always incrementing Wins and Losses.  Also Wins should be int, not double.